# Triple boot Windows, Ubuntu and MacOS

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, macosx

Is it possible (and if yes, could you, please, point me to somewhere I could learn how) to triple boot MacOS, Ubuntu and Windows 10, provided I already have Windows and Ubuntu installed (so I'd have to install MacOS [Hackintosh] last)? :)

Comment: If the Hackintosh install is on its own drive it's much easier.  Just leave your Windows and Ubuntu install alone and install MacOS on its own drive. With most systems, you can hit a key on boot to choose a boot device.  This way you don't even need grub.  This is how one of my laptops is setup with Windows and Ubuntu.  It boots into Windows unless I hit F11 on bootup and choose to boot off of my Linux drive.  Keeps them both completely separate from eachother and in my opinion, is much easier to setup and maintain.

Comment: Thank you! By separate drives, you mean separate HDDs, no? In that case,  I only have one, so I'd have to go with different partitions on the same drive.

Comment: Yes separate HDD's is what I meant.